# How connect to GCP Postgres intstance SQL instance using NpgsqlConnection with SSL certificates in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

my requirement is to connect to GCP SQL instance (Postgres) with SSL certificate. I did below steps:

1. Enabled SSL encryption in GCP console SQL instance
2. Downloaded certificates (client-cert.pem, client-key.pem and server-ca.pem)
3. Created connection string (var cs = "sslmode=require;TrustServerCertificate=true;Host=" + Host+ "; port=5432; Username=" +Username+"; Database="+Database+"; password="+Password;)
4. Then created connection object with NpgsqlConnection ( using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);)
5. Setting ProvideClientCertificatesCallback ( con.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += new ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(MyClientCertificates);)
6. Then tried to open the connection (con.Open();)

When trying to open the connection, I am getting below error;
"SSL connection requested. No SSL enabled connection from this host is configured."

How can we set a connection to GCP SQL with SSL certificates? any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

How can we set a connection to GCP SQL with SSL certificates using C# ? Given below is the code which I used and is not working. If anyone has some sample code/any help would be apprciated.

```
enter code here
string Username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_USER");
string Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_PASS"); 
string Database = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_NAME");
string Host="<private ip>";
var cs = "sslmode=require;TrustServerCertificate=true;Host=" + Host+ ";Username=" +Username+"; Database="+Database+"; password="+Password;
Console.WriteLine(cs.ToString());
using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
con.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += new
ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(MyClientCertificates);
con.Open();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.